# How to source a bash script in emacs' eshell

Tags: bash, emacs

I'm trying to use eshell inside emacs, so I don't have to switch between emacs and a terminal.
When using bash, I have few bash scripts I usually source to export some env variables (in order to switch between different tool-versions and build-environments).
Is it possible to somehow execute my scripts with bash, and put the exports (or some of them) in eshell.

Basically I'm trying to source a bash-script in eshell.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: This seems to be a common misunderstanding for some reason, but "source" does not mean "set a few variables"; it means (in the context of sh) "execute the commands in this file in the current context". Therefore, the answer to the question "can I source a bash file in a program that uses some other incompatible language?" is _no_.

Comment: @LaC - You should post your comment as an answer IMO

Comment: @Nifle - your wish is my command.

Answer (score 4):

I think, I found a way. I've created a `my-init.el` script with this content:

```
  bash -c "source my-init.sh > /dev/null && env |                   \
           grep -E 'MY_ENV\=' |                                     \ 
           sed -e 's/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/(setenv \"\1\" \"\2\" \)/g'"  \
           > /tmp/my-init-env
  source /tmp/my-init-env
```

When sourced from within eshell, it will start a bash, source the `my-init.sh` there (thus setting the `MY_ENV` variable), and then call `env` to obtain `MY_ENV`, and convert it with `sed` to something like `(setenv "MY_VAR" "value")` which is than sourced in the original eshell.

Not beautiful, but it does the job!

Comment: I asked a mod to remove the "community wiki" status. Then I upvoted you..

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common misunderstanding for some reason, but "source" does not mean "set a few variables"; it means (in the context of sh) "execute the commands in this file in the current context". Therefore, the answer to the question "can I source a bash file in a program that uses some other incompatible language?" is *no*.

Comment: I knew, what sourcing is, but was trying to find a solution/workaround. Anyway, thank you, for your reply!